# The current path, /django_plotly_dash/app/test/, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, plotly-dash, django-cms

We have a platform deployed on Django and we wanted to implement a dashboard created using plotly and dash in the existing Django application that we have. I followed some tutorials and integrated the dashboard application just the way everyone did but whenever I tried to go to the application url I get this message: The current path, /django_plotly_dash/app/test/, didn’t match any of these.

I have created an app cars_dashboard.

**settings.py:**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_plotly_dash.middleware.BaseMiddleware'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [    
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'channels',
    'channels_redis',
    'cars_dashboard'
]

CRISPY_THEME_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'cars_dashboard.routing.application'

PLOTLY_DASH = {
  'stateless_loader': 'cars_dashboard.dash_app.cars_dashboard',
  'cache_arguments': False,
  'serve locally': False
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [
                ('127.0.0.1', 6379),
                      ],
        },
    },
}

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAssetFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashComponentFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAppDirectoryFinder',
]

PLOTLY_COMPONENTS = [
    'dash_core_components',
    'dash_html_components',
    'dash_bootstrap_components',
    'dash_renderer',
    'dpd_components',
    'dpd_static_support',
]
```

main website's **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls')),
    path('cars_dashboard/', include('cars_dashboard.urls')),
]
```

cars_dashboard **views.py**

```
import django_plotly_dash
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'cars_dashboard.html')
```

cars_dashboard **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .dash_app import cars_dashboard


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

The third line in the above code import the cars_dashboard.py script which contains the code for dashboard and it is found  ./cars_dashboard/dash_app/cars_dashboard.py

Although I have a dashboard to implement but while debugging it I have created a very simple dashboard that only contains an html div for the sake of simplicity.
**cars_dashboard.py:**

```
import dash_html_components as html
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = DjangoDash('test', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Test Dashboard'),
])
```

In the script above I removed the line:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Test Dashboard'),
])
```

and then ran the application and got an error that a dash layout must be returned which certainly means that this application is being accessible.

I checked the StateApp Model in Django Admin and an app by the name of 'test' is created there. But the DashApps model is always empty.

I also tried with downgrading django_plotly_dash and dash to the recommended versions but no luck there as well.

My current Django version is 3.2.9 and I can't downgrade to any other option because it will mess up the compatibility with my whole project. I also have celery implemented in there for backend jobs. Could that be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Have you set `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings.py? I can't see it.

Comment: I only shared the content relevant to django_dash_plotly but like I mentioned this platform is entirely set up and working. The ROOT_URLCONF is present in the settings.py.

Comment: You did not, since `/django_plotly_dash/app/test/` points to `django_plotly_dash/urls.py` which you did not post. Instead, you posted `cars_dashboard/urls.py` which seems irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I have added the ROOT_URLCONF value which is found in my settings.py. The thing is that if I make any changes that will cause an error I get to see that error when I run the application, for instance when I changed the name of the application I received the error no stateless app by that name found which means the app is being recognized.

Comment: Share your `django_plotly_dash/urls.py` as we do not know which view is accessed. It seems you mix up some things as you shared `cars_dashboard/urls.py` which is not used for the URL `cars_dashboard`.